# Splitting a filename into words and numbers in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

The following code splits a string into a list of words but does not include numbers:

```
    txt="there_once was,a-monkey.called phillip?09.txt"
    sep=re.compile(r"[\s\.,-_\?]+")
    sep.split(txt)

['there', 'once', 'was', 'a', 'monkey', 'called', 'phillip', 'txt']
```

This code gives me words and numbers but still includes "_" as a valid character:

```
re.findall(r"\w+|\d+",txt)
['there_once', 'was', 'a', 'monkey', 'called', 'phillip', '09', 'txt']
```

What do I need to alter in either piece of code to end up with the desired result of:

```
['there', 'once', 'was', 'a', 'monkey', 'called', 'phillip', '09', 'txt']
```

Comment: If digits are adjacent to alphabetic characters, are they part of the word or a separate word? For example, should `"23skidoo"` split to `["23", "skidoo"]` or `["23skidoo"]`?

Comment: Should definately split to ["23","skidoo"].  I'm working with file names where i need to find months and dates to determine which batch they need to be allocated to.  The extra words are used to determine if the file is one we want, or something erroneous that requires user intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way that should do it:

```
re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+",txt)
```

Here's another:

```
re.split(r"[\s\.,\-_\?]+",txt)
```

(you just needed to escape the hyphen because it has a special meaning in a character class)

Answer (score 2):

For the example case,

```
sep = re.compile(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+")
sea.split(txt)
```

should work. To separate numbers from words, try

```
re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]+|\d+", txt)
```

Comment: Don't include the slashes in Python. They're not part of the regular expression. (The slashes are part of the substitution and matching operators in Perl, but for whatever reason some PCRE libraries seem to want regexes with slashes on the ends)

Comment: @David: I realized that shortly after posting. Thanks for the heads-up, though.

Comment: no problem, just wanted to clarify for anyone reading ;-) I'd remove my downvote now but it appears to be locked, unless you make another edit